# Browsers cause high cpu utilization

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cpu, freeze, high-cpu-usage

When I open a webpage, my browser will use 100% cpu, the page will load slowly, video/audio will freeze or sputter and the computer becomes generally unusable. This happens in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Even the mouse hesitates when moving the cursor.

I've tried everything I can think of aside from a remimage which I really don't want to do and am open to ideas.

- HP Envy Laptop
- Win10 pro 64 bit
- 16gb of ram
- Nvidia GeForce 940mx
- Latest drivers for video card (23.21.13.8873)
- Solid state drive
- 4 core i7 proc, 2.7ghz

I did a quick procmon capture while loading msnbc in Chrome and there were a bunch of reg queries where the result was 'name not found' but that's the only thing that stuck out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run Malwarebytes over it?

Comment: Malwarebytes didn't find anything "no threats detected"

Comment: Have a look at the CPU temp and frequencies - maybe the CPU is overheating and throttling down?

Comment: You may be on to something, I see the temp spike in speed fan when the cpu spikes, but I cannot seem to find a way to control it. I tried Notebook fan control software but that does not support my Hp Envy, do you have any suggestions for manipulating fan speed?

Comment: The temp spike could be normal - the CPU is doing rendering work - but do the CPU frequencies go up to 2.7 GHz?

Comment: I'm not sure how to see that? All i see is 3490mhz for both cores in CPUz software? How can I view the cpu clock speed?

Comment: assuming your CPU is overclockable to 3.5GHZ thats what you would expect if the CPU is working full tilt.

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons that you have adware in background , you need to cross check your device and uninstall any program you suspect it contain adware also download `adware removal` , antivirus such as `Avast` and `AVG`, can do the job.

Comment: I have avg and ran Malware bytes with "no threats found" . I don't install hardly anything on this computer and certainly not anything I didn't have a known history with (example is Office or Visual Studio)

Comment: lastly uninstall your browser and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

It's some times related to the Windows 10 Dynamic ticking.
Run Command Prompt as Administrator, type the commands below:
bcdedit /set useplatformclock false  Then type
bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes
Type bcdedit again to check the status.

It also can be related to the Windows 10 network components.
download TCP Optimizer and use the "optimal option"
https://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php
After doing these above, restart your system.